# Python / Sqlite3: LEFT JOIN with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: python, sqlite, left-join, group-concat

I have 2 Tables:

```
Tasks:                     Predecessors:

ID | Task | Team           ID | TaskID | PredecessorID
---+------+------          ---+--------+--------------
1  | A    | 1              1  | 1      | None
2  | B    | 1              2  | 2      | 1 
3  | C    | 2              3  | 3      | 1
4  | D    | 2              4  | 3      | 2
                           5  | 4      | None
```

I want to select **all Tasks from Team 2** and add the **Predecessors for each Task separated by commas** in that form:

```
ID | Task | Team | Predecessors
---+------+------+-------------
3  | C    | 2    | 1, 2
4  | D    | 2    | None
```

Therefore I use the following SQL-Query:

```
SELECT Tasks.*, GROUP_CONCAT(Predecessors.PredecessorID)
FROM Tasks LEFT JOIN Predecessors ON Tasks.ID = Predecessors.TaskID 
WHERE Tasks.Team = 2 GROUP BY Predecessors.TaskID
```

which returns:

```
ID | Task | Team | Predecessors
---+------+------+-------------
3  | C    | 2    | 1, 2
```

**What can I do to get get the line with the None Value too?**

Here is my test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

# Drop old tables if they already exits and create new ones. (For testing).
cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tasks""")
cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Predecessors""")

# Create tables.
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Tasks (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
               Task TEXT, Team INTEGER)""")
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Predecessors (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
               TaskID INTEGER, PredecessorID INTEGER)""")

# Insert some values.
sql = """INSERT INTO Tasks (Task, Team) VALUES (?, ?)"""
for task in [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 3)]:
    cur.execute(sql, task)

sql = """INSERT INTO Predecessors (TaskID, PredecessorID) VALUES (?, ?)"""
for predecessor in [(1, None), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, None)]:
    cur.execute(sql, predecessor)

con.commit()

sql = """SELECT Tasks.*, GROUP_CONCAT(Predecessors.PredecessorID)
FROM Tasks LEFT JOIN Predecessors ON Tasks.ID = Predecessors.TaskID 
WHERE Tasks.Team = 2 GROUP BY Predecessors.TaskID"""
cur.execute(sql)
data = cur.fetchall()
print data

con.close()
```

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `GROUP BY Predecessors.TaskID`; for a row without matches, all `Predecessors` columns are NULL.

Just use `GROUP BY Tasks.ID` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind to write me the whole query please? (Since I've never used the GROUP BY statement before and do not know exactly where to put it in my query)

Comment: Just replace it.

Comment: Sorry I did not read your answer carefully. I thought I should use a GROUP BY Statement instead of GROUP_CONCAT. Thats rubbish. The GROUP BY Statement solved my actual problem! Whereas obgnaws answers is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

you should check you code carefully.nothing wrong in your sql,you just write wrong test data.

```
your test data[('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 3)]
and it should be [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 2), ('D', 2)]
```

Comment: Oh that's right! Sorry. It worked when I corrected the code as you supposed!